# KieServices.Factory.get() get NullPointer Exception?

Tags: drools

When I use drools 7.8 in an android project, everything seems ok. But when I sign the app to make it a system-level app.That means I add `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system` in `Manifest.xml` . Then the `nullPointer` problem occurs.

```
    DroolsAndroidContext.setContext(this);
    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieModuleModel kieModuleModel = kieServices.newKieModuleModel();
```

When I delete the `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system` to make a normal signature it works well.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Could you please share the code where the NPE occurs?

Comment: Thank you, I put some codes .